# Cannot get username and password for jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I installed jenkins to windows 10.
When I accessed to http://localhost:8080/, I have to enter username and password.

But I don't show **secret** folder like displayed by that screenshot:

[image]

I got that exception when running `java -jar jenkins.war` inside the path folder containing **jenkins.war**

> webroot: $user.home/.jenkins 2020-06-23 14:24:23.610+0000 [id=1]
> INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging
> initialized @673ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
> 2020-06-23 14:24:23.704+0000 [id=1]     INFO
> winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
> 2020-06-23 14:24:26.204+0000 [id=1]     WARNING
> o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
> 2020-06-23 14:24:26.251+0000 [id=1]     INFO
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.27.v20200227;
> built: 2020-02-27T18:37:21.340Z; git:
> a304fd9f351f337e7c0e2a7c28878dd536149c6c; jvm 1.8.0_221-b11 2020-06-23
> 14:24:26.938+0000 [id=1]     INFO
> o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for
> /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet 2020-06-23
> 14:24:26.985+0000 [id=1]     INFO
> o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager
> workerName=node0 2020-06-23 14:24:26.985+0000 [id=1]     INFO
> o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set,
> using defaults 2020-06-23 14:24:26.985+0000 [id=1]     INFO
> o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging
> every 600000ms 2020-06-23 14:24:27.532+0000 [id=1]     INFO
> hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory:
> C:\Users\SariaEssid.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins 2020-06-23
> 14:24:27.688+0000 [id=1]     INFO
> o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@5f7f2382{Jenkins
> v2.235.1,/,file:///C:/Users/SariaEssid/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Users\SariaEssid.jenkins\war}
> 2020-06-23 14:24:27.688+0000 [id=1]     INFO
> o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStop: Stopped
> ServerConnector@7b4c50bc{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
> 2020-06-23 14:24:27.688+0000 [id=1]     INFO
> o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#stopScavenging: node0 Stopped
> scavenging 2020-06-23 14:24:27.704+0000 [id=1]     INFO
> hudson.WebAppMain#contextDestroyed: Shutting down a Jenkins instance
> that was still starting up java.lang.Throwable: reason
> at hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:417)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ContextHandler.java:940)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ServletContextHandler.java:565)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.stopContext(ContextHandler.java:908)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.stopContext(ServletContextHandler.java:367)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1450)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopContext(WebAppContext.java:1415)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:983)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop(ServletContextHandler.java:284)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:547)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:180)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:201)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:108)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:454)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
> at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:304)
> at winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:195)
> at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:355)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at Main._main(Main.java:375)
> at Main.main(Main.java:151) 2020-06-23 14:24:27.704+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStop: Stopped
> w.@5f7f2382{Jenkins
> v2.235.1,/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Users\SariaEssid.jenkins\war}
> Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread"
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
> at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:276) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:543)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> ... 1 more 2020-06-23 14:24:27.704+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Jetty shutdown successfully
> java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
> at winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:184)
> at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:355)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at Main._main(Main.java:375)
> at Main.main(Main.java:151) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:231)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
> at winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:182)
> ... 7 more Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
> at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
> at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
> at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
> at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
> at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
> ... 14 more 2020-06-23 14:24:27.720+0000 [id=1]     SEVERE  winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup failed
> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
> at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
> at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
> at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
> at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
> at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
> Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:231)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
> at winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:182) Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
> at winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:184)
> at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:355)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at Main._main(Main.java:375)
> at Main.main(Main.java:151)

Could you please help me solving that problem ?.

Any suggetion will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that command `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8383`.